# Save Parent Object and list of child object Same Time in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

**This is my entity classes**

```
    @Entity
        @Table(name="hdr_info")
        public class HdrInfo implements Serializable {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Id
            @Column(name="hdr_sr_no")
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private Integer HdrSrNo;

            @Column(name="comp_cd")
            private Integer compCd;

            //bi-directional many-to-one association to EppsMmMtrlReqDtl
            @OneToMany(mappedBy="hdrInfo")
            @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
            private List<DetailInfo> detailInfo;
            //getters and setters
        }
```

**Detail Info Entity class**

```
        @Entity
        @Table(name="detail_info")
        public class DetailInfo implements Serializable {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @Column(name="dtl_sr_no")
            private Integer dtlSrNo;

            @Column(name="active_yn")
            private String activeYn;

            @Column(name="short_close_qty")
            private BigDecimal shortCloseQty;

            @Column(name="short_close_rsn")
            private String shortCloseRsn;

            @Column(name="short_close_yn")
            private String shortCloseYn;

            @Column(name="sugg_brand")
            private String suggBrand;

            @Column(name="terminal_id")
            private String terminalId;

            @Column(name="transaction_stage")
            private Integer transactionStage;

            //bi-directional many-to-one association to EppsMmMtrlReqHdr
            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name="hdr_sr_no", nullable = false)
            private HdrInfo hdrInfo;

               //getters and setters
        }
```

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    HdrInfo hdr =new HdrInfo();
    hdr.setCompCd(1);
    List<DetailInfo> lst=new ArrayList<DetailInfo>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {                       
        DetailInfo dtl=new DetailInfo();

        dtl.setTransactionStage(Integer.parseInt("1"));
        dtl.setTerminalId("linuxPc01");
        dtl.setActiveYn("Y");

        dtl.setShortCloseYn("Y");

        dtl.setHdrInfo(hdr);
        lst.add(dtl);
    }
    hdr.setEppsMmMtrlReqDtls(lst);
    session.saveOrUpdate(hdr);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

now if i run main class to save HderInfo class with list of DtlInfoClass gives me error of same object Identifier  was found while saving List of DtlInfo,Now primary key of DtlInfo is also auto incremented then what is proper solution ??? help me !!!

Comment: You have bug in your main method. You created 3 DetailInfo objects and throwing it away. You're supposed to add it into HdrInfo.detailInfo list

Comment: sry forgot to add ,will correct it ,but then also it give me same error

Comment: there is more wrong... mappedBy="HdrInfo" should be mappedBy="hdrInfo" and you dont have an transaction begin. And you must initialize the arraylist details. Than add it in the main, this works for me without problems.

Comment: and error is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

## HdrInfo

```
private List<DetailInfo> detailInfos = new ArrayList<DetailInfo>();

public void addDetailInfo(DetailInfo detailInfo) {
    detailInfo.setParent(this);
    detailInfos.add(detailInfo);
}

public void removeDetailInfo(DetailInfo detailInfo) {
    detailInfos.remove(detailInfo);
    if (detailInfo != null) {
        detailInfo.setParent(null);
    }
}
```

## Main

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = session.beginTransaction();

    HdrInfo hdr = new HdrInfo();
    hdr.setCompCd(1);
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {                       
        DetailInfo dtl=new DetailInfo();

        dtl.setTransactionStage(Integer.parseInt("1"));
        dtl.setTerminalId("linuxPc01");
        dtl.setActiveYn("Y");

        dtl.setShortCloseYn("Y");

        hdr.addDetailInfo(dtl);
    }
    session.saveOrUpdate(hdr);

    tx.commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
    throw e;
}
finally {
    sess.close();
}
```

1. You need to explicitly start/commit/rollback a transaction.
2. Always [close the session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#close%28%29) to release allocated resources (db connections)
3. It's better to initialize all children collections from start
4. Prefer adding add/remove utilities when having bi-directional associations

Answer (score -1):

Here are some suggestions and try like that;

1. I am sure that you are trying to persist as new object instances to DB

   ```
   //session.saveOrUpdate(hdr);
   session.save(hdr);
   ```
2. Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in entity classes
3. as @pL4Gu33 said, care spelling of `mappedBy`
4. Open transaction before nay db update operation

   ```
   session.getTransaction().begin();
   ```

Comment: You do realise that session.save() does exactly the same thing as session.saveOrUpdate(). The only difference is that with session.saveOrUpdate() you won't get an exception thrown if your object already exists in the database. If this does fix the problem then the system has **far** deeper issues than getting a collection object to save by cascade. -1

Comment: Yes I know the difference between save() & saveOrUpdate(). So what is your suggestion on this question?

Comment: Remove the suggestion about session.save(), I wholeheartedly agree about overriding equals and hashcode, but not changing to session.save(), it is misleading as to the actual solution. If you can be bothered, OP's issue is with his cascade type and relationship mapping. I'd work it out but I have to go home :P

Comment: Sorry I am sure that the issue is testing to persist as new objects and not related to merge to any states in persistent context (cache memory). :D

Comment: I just done that  but getting error---org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:

Comment: Problem is that that list of object is not differed by compiler ,so it  gives same object identifier error in list,and as dtlInfo table have primary key which is autoincremented ,so it is not avilable before save it is generated after save ,then how can i solve this problem

Comment: So how to test with `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` instead of `IDENTITY` for id column? And what is underlying database? I prefer `Table` gen and `Sequence` gen, but not sure that your db support `Sequence`. By using one of them, you can allocate id gen as pool defining at entity level.